# Why zsh precommand modifiers stop accepting arguments if quoted?

Tags: zsh

`zsh` has precommand modifiers, which precede a command to alter how command is interpreted. Some of them are `command` and `exec`.

```
$ zsh -c 'exec -a foo zsh -c "print -- \$0"'
foo
$ zsh -c 'command -v ls'
/bin/ls
```

But they stopped accepting arguments if quoted:

```
$ zsh -c '\exec -a foo zsh -c "print -- \$0"'
zsh:1: command not found: -a
$ zsh -c '\command -v ls'
zsh:1: command not found: -v
```

Sounds like quoted them making them run immediately without processing other arguments.

It makes prevent alias named `command` or `exec` from expanding is impossible.

Is this a bug or a feature? Is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zsh parses precommand modifiers in the same way as aliases and keywords: they have to be at the beginning of a command, unquoted. This is pretty much necessary for modifiers that affect the parsing of the command (`noglob`, `nocorrect`). The precommand modifiers `builtin`, `command`, `exec` use the same logic internally even though they could be interpreted otherwise.

As far as I can tell, there's no deep reason for this logic, just that it was done this way a couple of decades ago and nobody has cared enough about this edge case to fix it.

Given that something like `\command -v ls` doesn't do anything sensible, it's definitely a bug.